# Return a reference but prevent it from being stored through a wrapper or other means

Tags: c++, architecture, c++17

In our code we sometimes return a non-const reference to the object for chaining method calls. For example:

```
registry.GetComponent(entityID).GetParams().GetTuners().SetWidth(50)
```

Sometimes in our reviews, we receive code that stores the reference and does something with it, which we forbid.

```
auto& comp = registry.GetComponent(2);

// ... do something with component
// ... with our pooling, comp could invalid at any point
```

We catch it most of the time, but sometimes it goes through and results in hard to find crashes. We tried implementing a wrapper (which stores private reference internally) that is returned instead of the references and this wrapper is non-copyable. Since the dot operator cannot be overloaded (that would have been perfect in this case), we overloaded the `()` operator instead.

So now we have

```
// all GetXXXXX are now const ref
// registry.GetComponent(entityID).GetParams().GetTuners().SetWidth(50)
registry.UpdateComponent(entityID)().UpdateParams()().UpdateTuners()().SetWidth(50)

// this is still possible, but easier to catch in code reviews
auto comp = registry.UpdateComponent(entityID);
comp().UpdateParams()().UpdateTuners()().SetWidth(50);
```

Ugly, but much more visible in code reviews, and if stored locally and then used, it's very easy to spot in code reviews as well.

Is it possible to return a reference to the modifiable object but prevent it from being stored OR a different pattern that allows us to safely modify nested objects.

> Notes: The above reflect our code somewhat, but are very contrived examples. I hope the intent of the question is clear.

Comment: "*we overloaded the () operator instead*" Wouldn't it make more sense to overload `->` instead?

Comment: if you want to encapsulate data don't return non-const references. Any workaround will just result in a mess

Comment: *but prevent it from being stored* -- If the programmer is brave enough to store references, then it is the fault of the programmer if that reference is invalidated later on.  Sounds like you're trying to prevent all [PEBCAC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAC#English) errors.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the caller to create a reference to your value (i.e. prevent something like `auto& ref = registry.GetComponent(entityID)`)? Or do you want to prevent the called to copy the value (i.e. `auto value = registry.GetComponent(entityID)`)?

Comment: @NicolBolas I did try that, but maybe I didn't go far enough. I assumed `->.` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude both

Comment: @Samaursa: The point of using `->` is to turn the more obtuse `().` syntax into something more comprehensible: `UpdateComponent(entityID)->UpdateParams()->UpdateTuners()->SetWidth(50)` That makes it clear at the API level that you're dealing with a pointer-like construct, so you shouldn't keep it around because what it points to is not necessarily owned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure, I did not think it through too much.

If you want to ensure that the reference can only be used to chaining, return by `&&` and implement the methods only for r-value `this`.

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct Component{
    Component&& incValue() &&{return std::move(*this);}
    Component&& decValue() &&{return std::move(*this);}
    const Component&& print() const &&{return std::move(*this);} 
// Make copy,move ctors private to disallow copies if necessary.
};

struct Registry{
    Component test;
    const Component&& getConstComponent(){ return std::move(test); }
    Component&& getComponent(){ return std::move(test); }
};
int main()
{
    Registry registry;

    registry.getComponent().incValue().decValue().print();
    registry.getConstComponent().print();

    //ERROR, & cannot bind &&
    //Component& comp = registry.getComponent();
    //const & can bind &&
    const Component& comp = registry.getComponent();
    // ERROR, print only works with const &&
    // comp.print();
    // Yes, this works (and is perfectly valid code), it is not fool-proof. 
    std::move(comp).print();
    //BEWARE, this allows easy theft of the Component's data via move ctor.
    Component thief{registry.getComponent()};
    return 0;
}
```

I do not recommend doing this, I only say it is possible and maybe it could be modified to help you. I would argue that not many developers are familiar with overloading based `&,&&` and it can become confusing.

Furthermore, it abuses move semantic by not doing any transfers of resources. Also, it can be overridden with `std::move` or direct cast, but it should at least give the user a pause.

This might not work if you use `Component` somewhere in normal way. One not so good workaround is to make l-value methods private and use `friend`. Much more sane version is to apply this logic to the wrapper only. The downside is the duplication of `Component`'s interface.

- `Registry::getComponent()` returns by value a `CompRef` wrapper that only has r-value methods which also return by value a copy of itself. This wrapper should be small, so hopefully `return CompRef by value+optimization == returning Component&`.
- Consider making copy, move ctors private to disallow storage. Since every copy is made inside `CompRef` itself.

**Note**: returning r-value of itself will only work in the chain, storing it will create a dangling reference since the original was a temporary. This should not be an issue since you should not really use it, but any access will become UB.

A middleground approach, but quite invasive, would to be partition `Component` into l-value and r-value(=chain-only) methods via inheritance. Then, `Registry` could return a r-value reference to the r-value view of the component only. This would allow to use the component both in normal and chain-only context.

Again, this will require more thought before putting in any codebase.

Comment: Interesting approach. We may end up using something similar, ty.

For your bullet points, #1 would be dangerous since the ref stored inside the wrapper can be invalidated and the wrapper copied around (especially in lambdas), #2 copies would be expensive and even more so when I need to update the original component after mutating the copy #3 surprisingly, neither MSVC++ nor Clang warn about this!

Comment: @Samaursa They will not be expensiv, I am not suggesting to copy the component itself, only the wrapper which is just `class W{ Component* comp;};` and a bounch of methods. If the copy constructor is deleted, it cannot be copied. Yes a reference can be captured by lambda, but so can a reference to any variable. It would have to be `const` to capture the temporary and it becomes l-value so no methoud could be called.